# Neo4j 2.0.1 pagination with SKIP/LIMIT returning repeated rows

Tags: neo4j

I do not have any hypothesis about why Neo4j is behaving in this manner, so I'm putting the basic essential information. If you need anything more, please ask.

I have the following query, I think the context is not very important. It is possible to grasp the intention only by the names.

```
MATCH (e:Evidence)-[*2]->(t:Term) 
WHERE e.description =~ {regexp} OR t.description =~ {regexp} OR t.name =~ {regexp} 
OPTIONAL MATCH (e:Evidence)-[*2]->(t2:Term) 
WHERE t2.description =~ {regexp} OR t2.name =~ {regexp} 
WITH e, count(t2) AS termsFound 
ORDER BY termsFound DESC 
SKIP 0 LIMIT 10 
RETURN e;
```

For some keyword used for the {regexp} param, the query returns 19 rows (both with and without pagination). But with pagination, the query returns repeated IDs.

```
WITH    PAGINATION: 480,584,692,638,829,797,366,337,920,637,310,737,949,411,766,479,533,562,637
WITHOUT PAGINATION: 480,584,692,638,829,797,366,448,337,920,310,737,949,411,766,479,533,562,637
```

The element with ID 637 is repeated in the last row of both pages (10th of the page SKIP 0 LIMIT 10 and 9th of the page SKIP 10 LIMIT 10).

This is really weird behavior. The only hypothesis for why this is happening is that my order condition (ORDER BY termsFound DESC) is returning the same number (1) for most rows, which in turn would make Neo4j not choosing the correct elements to return on second page.

**EDIT 1 (SPECIFIC VERSIONS)**

spring.data.neo4j = 3.0.1.RELEASE

neo4j.kernel = 2.0.1

neo4j.cypher = 2.0.1

neo4j.cypher.dsl = 2.0.1

Comment: Which exact version are you using?

Comment: Updated as requested. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checked the versions as requested by Michael Hunger and updated to the following numbers:

spring.data.neo4j = 3.1.0.RELEASE

neo4j.kernel = 2.0.3

neo4j.cypher = 2.0.3

neo4j.cypher.dsl = 2.0.1

Not sure where the problem was, but it was enough to solve the issue.